# Do new users actually read the rules

Tags: discussion, new-users, rules

I know when I first joined I didn't. It left me helpless, and I ended up going through 3 question bans. I have been trying to do better since, and have noticed the decrease in quality all the long time users mention around here. Question bans seem to happen a lot faster. Do the new users actually read the rules, or do they typically skip them?

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: After which question ban did you finally break down and read the posting guidelines?

Comment: 2 or 3 I can't remember. I know I got banned at number 3  because I was in a  serious rush and made a stupid mistake posting a question that only was missing a semicolon.

Comment: I'm not trying to say that I'm perfect, I'm just wondering if the reason for these problems may be related to not reading the rules.

Comment: Yes, I think that it is. Stack Overflow has stricter rules than most Q&A sites, so people often come here and just post whatever is on their minds. It seems that as people get more accustomed to the "rules" of posting on the wide-open web, they're less likely to lurk for a time than they used to be.

Comment: Probably. It was probably very soon after my second, so I was recovering from that

Comment: Also, I see a lot of user rage quit after their first bad question :P

Comment: I think I read (or at least skimmed) the rules before posting my first question, but I can't remember. Out of curiosity, why didn't you read the rules?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because I don't see how it can possibly be answered definitively or constructively by Meta users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a purely opinion-based question. There's no way anyone here can know if new users **read** the rules - logs could be analyzed to see what percentage follow links to get to them, but you can't tell they *read* them. At the very best, it could be considered a polling question that attracts a lot of "I did" and "I didn't when I joined", and that has no usefulness here.

Comment: New users could answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Stack Overflow has ~ 3.94M [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users). There is a badge for scrolling through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page - [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed).

> Awarded 320703 times

Quick math shows that it 8% of the users. The tour page is presented at sign up. If only 8% of the users can make it through there, I imagine someone sitting through the full set of documentation in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) is incredibly rare.

Comment: I can confess, I had been a member for over 2 years before I went to the tour page and got that badge. But I had read what to ask, how to answer etc pages, which doesn't give the badge. But I'm not saying most of the users without the informed badge would do the same. Most definitely not.

Comment: @Andy and your 8% doesn't count the users that just opened the tour, scrolled to the bottom for the badge, and closed the page.

Comment: Users that had already a banned account probably don't bother reading the rules again. I think that the badge count isn't a reliable way to determine how many new users read the rules.