# Mandatory timer to view how to ask / answer before posting first time

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems to me that most of the questions / answers in the low quality posts queue could be avoided if the user simply read the [ask]/[answer] pages.

I propose that an easy way to oblige the user to do so is to create a timer for the amount of time it takes an average person to read the pages and disallow posting until they've spent that much time each page before being posting a question question / answer for the first time.

If the user clicks next early they would be prompted by something along the lines of...

> Welcome to stackoverflow! We are sorry if you have already finished reading this page. Congratulations, you're a fast reader! The average user will take longer than you to read this page and to prevent users from ignoring this page you'll have to wait until the timer runs out. We really want new users to read and understand this page before posting for the first time to prevent common first post mistakes. Don't worry, you only have to read it once!
>
> Would you like to automatically redirect this page once the timer runs out?
> [Yes] [No]

*the wording could change*

There is absolutely nothing at this point to stop the user from grabbing a coffee and continuing to ignore the page, but I would like to think that if nothing else the boredom quotient would be enough to get user to read the page.

To approach this from a different angle, we could just set it up so that if the user clicks next within say 15 seconds it would prompt you with something along the lines of...

> Did you read this page? We will take your word for it but if you didn't there is some really useful information here which helps to prevent common first post mistakes.
> [Yes] [No]

*the wording could change*

Comment: What if you read faster than the average person?

Comment: Then you grab a coffee. I never said it was a perfect solution but it would help stop those who completely ignore those pages from doing so. And as it would only be on the first post of each kind for a user I don't think it would be a big hindrance

Comment: Why? They read the rules, why can't they use the site?

Comment: We're talking about (my guess) one minute, before a new user posts for the first time.

Comment: On the other side of the debate, what prevents someone from doing exactly what you suggest? Get up, get a coffee, return and click next without ever reading.

Comment: Nothing, but would it help some users to stop from skipping it entirely? I think so

Comment: Would you wait a minute if you got a message that said you haven't read all the rules, please spend more time getting familiar with the site. Or would you just leave?

Comment: The message could be nicer than that. Something like "we're sorry if you have already finished reading (wow you read fast!) but most users will take longer than that to read this. We really want new users to read and understand this page before posting for the first time. Don't worry, you only have to read it once"

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294337/189134

Comment: But all you have to do to get the badge is scroll through. And I have seen the badge on users who obviously havent read the pages.

Comment: I would think that this should be relatively easy to implement and while it would not make everyone read the pages I believe it would most definitely help the issue.

Comment: I suggested this kind of delay before.  It was not well-received.  If implemented, it should also cut down on the number of puppet accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your input, would you wait a minute if you were prompted with the message described in my question on your first post?

Comment: *Then you grab a coffee*  What's to prevent the new user who doesn't want to read the help pages from just sitting for a minute (or grabbing a coffee) until the timer expires and still avoid reading them? It's also why requiring a user to click through all the links on a page won't work; the act of visiting the page does not mean it was read and understood.

Comment: As I said above there is absolutely nothing stopping you from grabbing a coffee, but this is not meant to force the information down the readers throat but rather to give them a nudge implying "You really should make sure you read this". I didn't say it was a perfect solution, or that it would even work for a majority. What it would do is cause those who do have something valuable to add to the community, but are in a rush for one reason or another to slow down and read it.

Comment: `We are sorry if you have already finished reading this page (wow you read fast!)` I'd immediatly quit the website. I read very fast, and this is not supposed to be held **against** me. I won't just go grab a coffee---why should I be denied normal usage just because I read faster? This is frustrating at best, and won't change anything at worst as everyone could just pick a coffee rather than read.

Comment: ok so we could pick better wording, i didn't mean it as an insult but rather a compliment. Remember this is a one time thing. How about we change it so that if you click next withing say 10 seconds it would just give you a prompt saying `Did you read this page? We will take your word for it but if you didn't there is some really useful information for first time users here. [Yes I did read the page] [I will go back and read]`. Just some kind of nudge to stop users from skipping through

Comment: Um... Doesn't presenting the page to them, asking them to read it, and asking them to be obligated to complete the tour do all of that already? How much more of a *nudge* do they need? *Here are three things we ask to to do before you post your first question. Oh, wait! We'll add a fourth you can ignore as well!* doesn't seem to be worth the effort.

Comment: All of those things can easily be blocked out by the user but a prompt (in my opinion) will generally make the user stop and think, at least for a second. This isn't meant as a catch-all but  rather a last line of defense

Comment: At which point do you stop adding *a last line of defense*? There are already three items. The object of these sites is not to see how many barriers to access we can build - it's to create a collection of shared knowledge. Voting and closures deal with the bad questions already, and I don't see how adding yet another *line of defense* will accomplish anything but make it more difficult for users who *do* intend to be good participants here from getting started.

Comment: How long until I get to answer this?

Comment: I *really* hope this doesn't get closed soon.  Not only did I find out that [I read at about ~850 WPM with > 85% accuracy](http://www.readingsoft.com/), I'm doing a few queries to refute this (and get the average post size across badges).

Comment: @Makoto: I got results of 660 wpm and 1660 wpm without making much additional effort to increase my speed. So uh... yeah, I don't know how accurate that test is. Still, it's interesting.

Comment: I put very little faith in the results of the test, but I do know that I read extremely quickly with high levels of comprehension.  It's more or less for a barometer and to get a feel for some averages.  The test bit was pretty entertaining at least.

Comment: [sf] already has [such a page](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice?). To continue and ask your first question, you have to tick the box before clicking proceed.

Comment: I just want to point out that on [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295178/4639281) in the comments @HanzPassant suggested a 24 hour period after registering before a user can post for the first time, which at this time has 55 upvotes. I think in relation to that 5 minutes to view a page twice in the entire lifetime of a user account isn't a very big leap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are *several* things that are askew with your proposal.

- The total size of "What questions can I ask here?" and "What shouldn't I ask here?" in characters are 3,200 and 2,267 respectively.  If you take the [average of a word](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=average+english+word+length) at face value, then you're looking at 628 and 445 words respectively, with no extra filler text like code blocks contained in it.
- The *average* words contained in a Stack Overflow question across the top twenty tags [varies between ~211 and 280 words](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/319214/average-question-size-with-word-count?opt.withExecutionPlan=true#executionPlan), and that *includes* filler like code blocks.
- The *average* words per minute that a user reads [is on the order of 200WPM](http://www.readingsoft.com/).

From that, we gather:

- It'd take 3-5 minutes for a new user to read both documents with varying levels of comprehension
- A new user can read a question from anywhere between 63 and 84 **seconds**, simply going from the average, with varying levels of comprehension
- From the numbers alone, a user will begin interacting with the community - for better or worse - 54-79% *faster* than reading the help articles.

That said, from a practical standpoint, there's no way you can force someone to read something before participation.

Then again, it's also attacking the wrong side of the low quality question problem.

There are people out there that are willing to post the most abstract, broad, and wild questions that they can think of (or are required to solve per their job), and for them, the quality of their questions will *never* improve regardless of what it is we do to help them.

In that scenario, the best thing to do is downvote, vote to close and delete some of the most egregious stuff out there.  It's going to keep coming in, and some of the best weapons we have to fight it are *already here*.